# Scrollable div (div height > browser height)

Tags: css, scroll

An scrollable div is easy to implement if it's height is minor than the browser's window height. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/y59ttm8s/4/ You can scroll the red div with an 'inner scrollbar', and that's fine.

HTML

```
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.scrollable {
    margin-left: 30px;
    float: left;
    height: 400px;       // with a fixed height!
    width: 65px;
    background: red;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content {
    height: 1450px;
}
```

Now, check the example modified: https://jsfiddle.net/y59ttm8s/5/ where the height of the scrollable div is 100%. I can't scroll anymore with the inner scrollbar, just with the browser's scrollbar.

CSS updated

```
.scrollable {
    margin-left: 30px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;                       // 100% !
    width: 65px;
    background: red;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content {
    height: 1450px;
}
```

So, how I can force to scroll with the div's scrollbar instead of the browser's one?

Comment: if you set height 100% the parent will be tall as much as the inner content, so no scrollbar is needed: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with browser height. In your second fiddle you can't scroll because you don't have scrollable content. All the `content` div fits in the `scrollable` container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the `body` a height or else the `scrollable` doesn't have from where to get its height.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.scrollable {
 margin-left: 30px;
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 width: 65px;
 background: red;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content {
 height: 1450px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="scrollable">
   <div class="content">
          
   </div>
 </div>
```

A second option is to change it to viewport units.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.scrollable {
 margin-left: 30px;
 float: left;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 65px;
 background: red;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content {
 height: 1450px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="scrollable">
   <div class="content">
          
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the hint with the viewport units was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this given below snippet will help you.

```css
body{margin:0; padding:0;}
.scrollable {
  margin:0;padding:0;
 margin-left: 30px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 65px;
 background: red;
 overflow-y: scroll;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}

.content {
 height: 1450px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="scrollable">
   <div class="content"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `absolute: position` should absolute not be used to solve something as simple as this.